# How can I fake the system's date while e2e-testing a Meteor project with Chimp?

Tags: meteor, integration-testing, fixtures

I'm working on an e-commerce website in which customers can rent a product for one week. One constraint is that a product needs to be cleaned during 2 days before being rented to another customer. So I'm writing Chimp+Cucumber (end-to-end) tests to make sure that a second customer cannot rent a same product before it was cleaned.

As customers can choose their week day of delivery, I would like to specify dates in my scenario without tweaking the DB or back-end methods. In my opinion, a good way to go would be to change the system's date (server + client), so that I can hard-code dates in my test specs.

Has anyone ever done that? I would like to hear your suggestions if you have any!

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the system date, that's really not a good idea. The number of things it will break - you have no idea!

Instead, use a setup step to execute direct SQL to insert entries into your database representing the previous transactions. E.g. one for a product which has been cleaned for two days and one which has not, then test against those entries. SQL can include date logic so you can do e.g. today - 1 day.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but isn't it bad practice to manipulate the DB from end-to-end tests? I wish there is another way!

Comment: It's a test database, right? No, it's not bad practice as long as you reset the **test database** afterwards, e.g. by restoring a known state backup or reversing the changes you made.

Answer (score 1):

This is the point where sanity should kick in, and if you haven't already started, unit test your code. It's far more convenient and robust for test date dependant logic, as well as most other business logic. e2e tests can be useful for many scenarios like acceptance tests. Keep the finer grained edge case testing to low level tests. Keep higher level page flow in e2e. It's also much easier to maintain unit tests over e2e.